# calculate difference between two queries in grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have a grafana dashboard with 2 influx queries which calculate a single value (`A` and `B`)

I now need to calculate the difference between those to `A - B`.
Is this somehow possible within influx or grafana?

Note, the two values come from the same database but from different measurements

[image: grafana dashboard]

Answer (score 11):

To show the difference of your two queries you first need to select the "Transform" tab.
Then "Add field from calculation".
Select your field names A and B.
Choose "Difference" as calculation method.
Select "Replace all fields" if you only want to see the difference.

Comment: Nice new grafana interface. Is it possible to see the difference graphs only, if I have several metrics?
I mean A-B and A-C. "Replace all fields" do not help and hiding the source metrics by eye icon too.